# I am trying to translate object in 2D space to the mouse position with respect to parent's transformation

Tags: c++, math, glm-math

I 've got hierarchy of the bones. Each bone might has parent and children. Each bone has it's local model matrix and world model matrix. I want to translate bone to the position of the mouse. I am using glm library.

This is how I did it:

```
// boneWorldOrigin is the position of the bone in the world
// boneOrigin is the position of the bone relative to it's parent
glm::vec2 diff = (m_MousePosition - boneWorldOrigin) + boneOrigin;
glm::mat4 translation = glm::translate(glm::vec3(diff, 0.0f));
// angle is the local rotation of the object
glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), angle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
// Local transformation of the object
m_Bone->Transform = transform * rotation;
```

It works only if the parent of the translated bone is not rotated.
I do not handle scaling at all. I would like to know how to handle this properly.

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found out I should convert mouse position from the world space to the local space of the bone parent.

```
translation = glm::inverse(parentBone->FinalTransform) 
* glm::translate(glm::vec3(m_MousePosition, 0.0f));

glm::mat4 rotation = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), angle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
m_Bone->Transform = translation * rotation;
```

Please let me know if there is more elegant solution. Or if it is correct solution at all